# XCFramework with pod dependencies

Tags: swift, xcframework

I am trying to build a framework in Xcode. Using Cocoapods as dependency manager and adding `pod 'Alamofire'` to the target.

Here are more details -

1. This project I have created using Xcode -> File -> New -> Project -> iOS -> Framework & Library -> Framework.
2. Since the project is having dependencies I am opening the xcworkspace file as per the instruction after running `pod install` command on terminal.
3. Added one Aggregate target to the same project under targets section.
4. Added a new run script from Project -> Targets -> Aggregate target -> Build Phases.
5. Added the steps to create xcframework instructed by apple to the run script.
6. Tried building the Aggregate target now.
7. Finally it is producing errors like - `linker command failed or no such module Alamofire etc.`
8. Tried lot many changes and instructions from internet but nothing helped so far.

[image]

```
I am using -
 Xcode - 12.5.1
 Swift - 5.0. 
 Macos - 11.5.
```

Is it a bug of Xcode or any special thing I need to take care during the process or I am doing it completely wrong?

Note - This one is a very simple project for testing out the xcframework build process with pods. Actually we have a project with multiple sub targets as frameworks which we are planning to build as xcframeworks and link with the main project target.

Answer (score 2):

Try add this post install step to your Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      config.build_settings['BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION'] = 'YES'
    end
  end
end
```

And in your `xcodebuild archive` make sure to have:

```
SKIP_INSTALL=NO BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES
```